# Network tasks with Android's AsyncTask result in very varying latencies

Tags: android, performance, android-asynctask, udp, latency

I'm developing a small and very simple app, where one Android device sends a small message over the network to another Android device. Android won't let me do network tasks on the main thread, so I used AsyncTask. The functionality is as following:

When a button is pressed on Device1, a AsyncTask is created and executed. The ASyncTask sends a "ping" message with UDP to Device2. Device2 is operating in a while(true) loop, and as soon as it receives the "ping" message, it sends a "pong". Device1 is waiting for this "pong" message.

The time is measured from the moment Device1 sends "ping" untill it receives "pong". If the button is pressed multiple times, the latency of each ping-pong drops dramatically to 2-5ms, but the first ping-pong can have latencies varying between 60-350ms. If the button is not pressed for some time and then pressed again, a typical latency is also between 60-350ms.

Is there anyone who can explain this behaviour? Is there a way to always achieve the low latencies (~5ms)?

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Android turns off WiFi when there's no traffic - see the analysis and the solution here: [Force android to send UDP packets immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13558283/force-android-to-send-udp-packets-immediately?rq=1). Basically, you need to send a keep-alive packet every now and then (like 100ms).

Comment: Thank you very much. This indeed is exactly the problem but I would never have I found it myself I guess... Thank you!

Comment: Is it ok like this? Sorry I am new at this website :)